# Usage of "$this->" outside an object in SalesForce example

Tags: php, salesforce

Several times a construct like  `$this->_mySforceConnection` is used in the following code sample on salesforce.com:

```
<?php

// SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR - folder that contains the PHP Toolkit and your WSDL
// $USERNAME - variable that contains your Salesforce.com username (must be in the form of an email)
// $PASSWORD - variable that contains your Salesforce.com password

define("SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR", "../../soapclient");
require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');
require_once ('../userAuth.php');
try {
  $mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
  $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/enterprise.wsdl.xml');
  $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);

  $sObject = new stdClass();
  $sObject->FirstName = 'George';
  $sObject->LastName = 'Smith';
  $sObject->Phone = '510-555-5555';
  $sObject->BirthDate = '1927-01-25';
  $sObject->Email = 'test@test.com';

  $createResponse = $this->_mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject), 'Contact');
  echo "Creating New Contact\r\n";
  print_r($createResponse);

  $sObject->FirstName = 'Bill';
  $sObject->LastName = 'Clinton';

  $upsertResponse = $this->_mySforceConnection->upsert('Email', array ($sObject), 'Contact');
  echo "Upserting Contact (existing)\r\n";
  print_r($upsertResponse);

  $sObject->FirstName = 'John';
  $sObject->LastName = 'Smith';
  $sObject->Email = 'testNew@test.com';

  echo "Upserting Contact (new)\n";
  $upsertResponse = $this->_mySforceConnection->upsert('Email', array ($sObject), 'Contact');
  print_r($upsertResponse);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $mySforceConnection->getLastRequest();
  echo $e->faultstring;
}
?>
```

I see that `$mySforceConnection` is an object, but what does
`$this->_mySforceConnection` refer to?  Why would `$this->` be used outside an object? How does it work? My only guess is that they are doing something really strange in their object that I've never heard of before.

Comment: `$this` is used *inside* a class to reference the instance of that class. It cannot be used outside. Use the variable holding the object instead

Comment: I'm not asking how to do it; it doesn't look right to me.  But this is an example on the salesforce.com website, and I assume it works.  I just want to know how or why they would do that, rather than simply writing $mySforceConnection->create.

Comment: Unless that code is within a class, It won't work as written